# IF a href string contains hide parent

Tags: javascript, jquery

if div class is `list-view` and articles a href contains string `staticcards` hide article & show article with a href string `listcards`

If div class is `card-view` and article a href contains string `listcards` hide article & show article with a href string `staticcards`

Below is the code, doesn't work

```js
if ($(".cards-wrapper").hasClass("list-view")) {

  $('a[href*="staticcard"]').parent().hide();
  $('a[href*="listcard"]').parent().show();

} else if ($(".cards-wrapper").hasClass("card-view")) {

  $('a[href*="staticcard"]').parent().show();
  $('a[href*="listcard"]').parent().hide();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="cards-wrapper list-view">
  <article>
    <a href="xxxxx?staticcard">Static Card</a>
  </article>
  <article>
    <a href="xxxxx?listcard">List Card</a>
  </article>
</div>
```

Comment: It doesn't work because there's no element with the class `cards-wrapper` did you mean for it to be `<div class="list-view cards-wrapper">`?

Comment: div will have a class cards-wrapper, i forgot to add it in my html

Comment: Are you [waiting for the dom to be ready](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/) before running your code as in the snippet above it seems to work fine

Comment: its loading at the bottom of the page

Answer (score 0):

Modularize, clean then use it.

```js
var wrapper = document.getElementsByClassName("cards-wrapper")[0];
if (Array.from(wrapper.classList).indexOf("list-view") > 0) {
Array.from(wrapper.getElementsByTagName("a")).filter(e=>e.href.indexOf("staticcard")>1).map(q=>q.style="display:none;");
}else {
Array.from(wrapper.getElementsByTagName("a")).filter(e=>e.href.indexOf("listcard")>1).map(q=>q.style="display:none;");
}
```

```html
<div class="cards-wrapper card-view">
  <article>
    <a href="xxxxx?staticcard">Test 1</a>
  </article>
  <article>
    <a href="xxxxx?listcard">Test 2</a>
  </article>
</div>
```

```js
var wrapper = document.getElementsByClassName("cards-wrapper")[0];
if (Array.from(wrapper.classList).indexOf("list-view") > 0) {
Array.from(wrapper.getElementsByTagName("a")).filter(e=>e.href.indexOf("staticcard")>1).map(q=>q.style="display:none;");
}else {
Array.from(wrapper.getElementsByTagName("a")).filter(e=>e.href.indexOf("listcard")>1).map(q=>q.style="display:none;");
}
```

```html
<div class="cards-wrapper list-view">
  <article>
    <a href="xxxxx?staticcard">Test 1</a>
  </article>
  <article>
    <a href="xxxxx?listcard">Test 2</a>
  </article>
</div>
```

Comment: just call q.parentNode.style = "display:none" instead q.style = "display:none" if you want to hide parent element